# "hello world" parser for lemon

Tags: php, pear, lexer, parser-generator, lemon

I try my best for hours now to create a y-file for the lemon parser (respectivly PEAR's PHP_LexerGenerator) that parses a simple "hello + world".

I used [this (German) tutorial](http://blog.oncode.info/2007/10/25/eine-eigene-programmiersprache-erschaffen-lexer-und-parser-in-php/) and yes it's nice to have a calculator tutorial, but at the end, I want to parse some more complex stuff (with "variables").

What would be the definition for this "language" parsing/tokenizing "hello + world"?

This is among many other things what I tried:

```
/* %name, %declare_class, %token_prefix, %syntax_error, .. removed */

%left S.
%left PLUS MINUS.

%right IDENT.

start(res)       ::= expression(expr). { res = expr; }

/* The common stuff */
expression(res)  ::= expression(e1) PLUS expression(t2). { res = e1+t2; }
expression(res)  ::= expression(e1) MINUS expression(t2). { res = e1-t2; }
expression(res)  ::= NUMBER(n). { res = n; }
expression(res)  ::= IDENT(n). { res = (n * 0) + 99; }
```

Instead of IDENT, I also tried VALUE, string, ... Not even the [SQLite/parser.y file](http://read.cs.ucla.edu/~vandebo/sqlite/source/parse.y) did help me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I recommend you don't use the PEAR/PHP-port of Lemon: it's in alpha-release, isn't maintained (since 2010!) and has next to no documentation.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You might have a look at [PHP PEG](https://github.com/hafriedlander/php-peg) (note that I never used it, so I can't say if it's any good or not). But personally, I'd choose a language other than PHP. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators